# SharePoint 2013 Filters

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, date

I am trying to create a filter for a calendar of events.  In the calendar of events, I am only wanting to show 30 days of events in the view.  I have a start date field and a calculated field called 30daysCalculated.  How do I set the filter to only pull those dates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is `Start Date >= [Today] and Start Date <= [Today] + 30`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you suggested wont work because of the drawback of calculated columns. Calculate columns gets its value only when it gets created or modified. Using above formula, if you are putting true/false or number of days in calculated column, it will remain static until you edit the item again. And once you edit the item, it recalculate data from today. So the logic will fail.

You can follow these steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Create a new view in your Event list, lets name it `Monthly Events`.
2. Now go to the filter section of view and add condition. Where `Start Date is greater than equal to Today` and `Start Date less than equal to Today + 30`.

In this way, you'll get a view displaying only 30 days of Events from today.